# How to define prototype method inside class definition (externally) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, es6-class

I have a class declaration which is quite large with lots of methods.

It's something like this:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    // ...code
  }
  config() {
    // ...code
  }
  theme() {
    // ...code
  }
  register() {
    // ...code 
  }
  render() {
    // ...code
  }
  write() {
    // ...code
  }
}
```

I'd like to split the source code up so it's easy to manage and read.

Is there a way I can assign a method to a class dynamically within the class itself?

I'd like to do something like:

```js
function bar(value) {
  if (value) {
    this.baz = 'baz'
    return this
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    // ...code
  }
  new bar() // Would reference function above ^ (not valid)
}
```

I know this is not valid or correct but because the class syntax automatically creates and binds a property called `bar()` to the prototype of `Foo` I can't think how you would do it, and perhaps the functionality doesn't exist.

The closest I can think to splitting the code up, is to extend a class but this seems a bit verbose.

```js
class Bar {
  bar() {
    if (value) {
      this.baz = 'baz'
      return this
    }
  }
}
```

```js
class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
```

`bar()` is now in Foo's prototype.

This method also offers little control to creating aliases if needed and also is harder to make it clear what methods that are available in the `Foo` class.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways of adding external functions as **own** properties:

1. Set it as a property of the `this` inside the constructor of the class.
2. Set it as a public property of the `class`, this is the [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

The downside is that, all the instances will not share the same function object as it becomes an own property. Own properties are used for holding state not functions.

To add in **prototype**, which is where methods in ES6 class are added, so that all instances share the same function object. You have to add it to the `prototype` property of the `class`. This works as `class` is a syntactic sugar of the `function` constructor and every function has a `prototype` property which is inherited by all instances of that `class`.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    // ...code
    this.bar = bar; //becomes own property
  }
  
  //As a public field, becomes own property
  baz = baz;
  
}
function bar(){
  console.log("from bar");
}
function baz(){
  console.log("from baz");
}
function foobar(){
 console.log("from foobar");
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
foo.baz();
//Set it directly on the prototype prop of the Class
Foo.prototype.foobar = foobar; 
foo.foobar();
```

> Also, I presume there isn't a way to set a prototype of a class inside
>   the class definition itself?

From your question in the comment, yes you can set the function in the prototype of the `class` inside the class definition itself:

```js
function bar(){
  console.log("bar in prototype");
  console.log("accessing data from this: ", this.data);
}

class Foo{
 constructor(){
   this.data = "data"
   Foo.prototype.bar = bar;
   Foo.prototype.thisBar = bar.bind(this);
 }
 //methods are added in prototypes
 baz(){
  console.log("baz in prototype");
 }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
foo.baz();
//accessing from prototype, here this is global context and will print undefined
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo).bar();
//this is bound so always refers to the instance
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo).thisBar();
//same for methods in es6
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo).baz();
```

For static methods just set it either as a property of the `class` or set it as public `static` property.

```js
class Bar{
  constructor(){
    //some logic
  }
  static baz = baz;
}
function foo(){
  console.log("from foo");
}
function baz(){
  console.log("from baz");
}
Bar.foo = foo;
Bar.foo();
Bar.baz();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'd like to be able to set it directly on the prototype of the class, but if my method references this (when used a constructor), is there a way I can set a method this way? I tried to update my question to show this more clearly.

Comment: Also, I presume there isn't a way to set a prototype of a class inside the class definition itself?

Comment: @limitlessloop you can access the `prototype` property of the class and add it there. I have shown that approach in the answer

Comment: why are you using `new bar()` ?

Comment: I think because when I had it as a class method it was referencing `this` so the only way to make it work externally was to use it as a constructor. But perhaps I can remove `this` and I don't need to use a constructor.

Comment: @limitlessloop did I address your query in the new edit of the answer?

Comment: Having removed the need for `this` and seeing that you can use `Foo.prototype.bar = bar` inside the Class directly, this has answered my question. Thank you. It's a shame though there isn't a more syntastic way to do this.

Comment: `this` refers to the current context of execution, you can also add a function having a `this` in the body to the prototype. When you call that function through the class instance the `this` will point to that instance, but if you don't then this will take the current execution context to fix it use `bind` to capture the this of the lexical context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198653/discussion-between-limitlessloop-and-amardeep-bhowmick).